# ¿Cómo mostrar miniaturas de SVG en el Explorador de Archivos de Windows?

Tags: windows, archivo, svg

Quisiera mostrar miniaturas (thumbnails) de imágenes SVG en el explorador de archivos de Windows.

[Pregunta original en inglés en superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/342052/how-to-get-svg-thumbnails-in-windows-explorer)

Comment: Esta pregunta no trata sobre programación o herramientas de programación dentro del alcance definido en el [centro de ayuda](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Es posible, aunque creo que el tema puede ser útil para los técnicos que trabajamos con este formato y de momento no tenemos un Superuser en Español. Por favor, reconsidera tu voto.

Comment: Que esté cerrada no quiere decir que la pregunta vaya a desaparecer (no se borrará porque tiene una respuesta, aunque deberías aceptarla), simplemente no se aceptarán más respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mostrar miniaturas de imágenes SVG en Windows, puedes instalar esta increíble extensión [SVG thumbnail shell extension](https://github.com/maphew/svg-explorer-extension/releases). Funciona en Windows 7, 8 y 10 (tanto en 64-bit como 32-bit).

> Modulo de extensión para el Explorador de archivos de Windows para renderizar miniaturas SVG, para tener una vista previa de tus archivos SVG.

Es gratuito y open source. Si tienes problemas para ver las miniaturas después de la instalación, echa un vistazo a [estas instrucciones](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-the-icon-cache-windows) (inglés).

Si tienes problemas en Windows 10, prueba a cambiar la asociación del archivo (con "Abrir con...").